# What does this exception (java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException) mean?

Tags: exception, orientdb

What does this exception mean? I keep getting it when I try to execute a query with JDBC.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 252
at com.orientechnologies.common.serialization.types.OLongSerializer.deserializeLiteral(OLongSerializer.java:69) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.readLong(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:788) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.readSingleValue(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:307) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.deserialize(ORecordSerializerBinaryV0.java:195) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.serialization.serializer.record.binary.ORecordSerializerBinary.fromStream(ORecordSerializerBinary.java:74) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.deserializeFields(ODocument.java:1817) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.checkForFields(ODocument.java:2416) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.record.impl.ODocument.fieldNames(ODocument.java:736) ~[orientdb-core-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcResultSet.<init>(OrientJdbcResultSet.java:59) ~[orientdb-jdbc-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcPreparedStatement.executeQuery(OrientJdbcPreparedStatement.java:70) ~[orientdb-jdbc-2.1.11.jar:2.1.11]
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:688) ~[spring-jdbc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at
```

Comment: It means the array index is out of bounds...

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This means that your database is corrupt. Try to repair it with `repair database` command from the orientdb console.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call an array index that does not exist.

eg.
If you have an array of 3 values and you try call the 4th value